# Pycharm running in different console

Tags: python, pycharm, console

I am using pycharm recently and one day I accidentally clicked something and now when I press F5 which I set to running the program, it shows up like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3RoC.png)

How do I change it back to when I run my program, it does the finished with exit code 0, like [this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/487vw.png)

I get my expected results for different programs but not for this one.

Comment: you selected `Run with Python Console` either in the properties or the run configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your run setting.

You have selected "run on Python console" (bottom part of options), so every run, it will open a new console and run within there your code.

Note: there is also the option "Allow parallel run" on very top. This has a similar effect but without giving you the console prompt.